# Sum with conflicting specifier

Tags: summation

This is the fomula (there might be some terms added, it is just boiled down to these two sums):
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{N} \Big(\ Term_i * \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} x_j\ \Big)$$
The outer sum will iterate from $0$ to $N$ and the inner one from $0$ to $i - 1$.
It has a recursive character.
Is the inner sum valid on the first term ($i = 0 $ and $j = -1$)?

Or do I have to rewrite the formula this way:
$$Term_0 + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \Big(\ Term_i * \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} x_j\ \Big)$$

This is all about how to write down the formula in a correct manner.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with initial term. Although upper one makes no sense when i=0

Comment: When $i=0$, the inner sum is empty. This is not a problem.

Comment: But then $j \gt i$ will occour, is this valid?

Comment: More general: is there a NEED of the starting index $j$ to be less or equal to the ending one?

Comment: You can define $\sum_{j=0}^{-1} x_j = 0$ or just shift the indeces of $x_j$ so $x_0 = 0$ than you can use $\sum_{j=0}^{i} x_{j}$. or you use the second term which is easier to understand anyway!

Comment: $j>i$ does not occur. The sum is over all $j$ that satisfy $j\ge0$ and, simultaneously, $j\le-1$. There are no such $j$, so the sum is over the empty set --- it's an empty sum --- this is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson, I'd like to accept this one as answer, if you post it as one. Also kudos to the other commentators, I apprecciate this!

Comment: Will do, if I get the time --- but it's OK with me if you want to post it as an answer, now that you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

> When $i=0$, the inner sum is taken over all $j$ that satisfy $j\ge 0$ and, simultaneously, $j\le-1$. There are no such $j$, so the sum is over the empty set. The empty sum contributes nothing, i.e., $0$. -- [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749516/sum-with-conflicting-specifier#comment1564360_749516) (slightly edited)